# Pokemon keep running away- is there any way to stop them?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been playing Pokemon for a few weeks, and yesterday I tried to do a GPS/location spoof and removed all the software, however, I can no longer catch Pokemon without them running away.

Is there any way this will stop (or I can stop them)?

Comment: you must not cheat

Comment: I am not a regular cheater at anything! But im really lazy

Comment: a friend, who is also lazy, used spoof software and after that (removing it) he couldnt locate his phone anymor. had to reinstall. did you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, shame on you!

Believe me, I know lazy but I'm glad this game came out because now I'm actually way more active and spend more time outside :D.

So put it aside and go catch some Pokemon the legit way because in a few hours you'll be able to do everything again

["The ban, however, is temporary, lasting for a few hours"](http://bgr.com/2016/07/15/pokemon-go-cheating-ban/)

This link says that:

> But if you use more advanced tactics that include GPS spoofing or using modified versions of the game, then Niantic and Nintendo will take action against cheating.
>
> Players who were dealt bans for using GPS spoofing hacks could no longer catch Pokemon, collect PokeStops, or battle/claim a gym, Polygon reports.
>
> The players discovered that the Pokemon would just run away when hit with a PokeBall, rather than adding itself to their collection.
>
> The ban, however, is temporary, lasting for a few hours, which means cheaters can get back to cheating once that’s done.

and:

["As one player said, it's only a soft ban and the inability to effectively play the game only lasts for a couple of hours."](http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/12/12159908/pokemon-go-cheating-ban-gps-spoofing)

Which says:

> As one player said, it's only a soft ban and the inability to effectively play the game only lasts for a couple of hours. It's an interesting discovery considering when players tried to use GPS spoofing technology during the game's beta stage, they were met with harder bans from Niantic, who seem to have dialed back the punishment being doled out to players caught cheating.

That being said, it could very well be that you'll be banned permanently if you try this too often.